# iFrame file upload with IE produces download dialogue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a custom module for Drupal dealing with Document Management. At this point, the module loads, you can upload files (via a hidden iframe and some ajax requests), browse directories and set various levels of permissions. And everything works perfectly in Firefox.

**Issue:**
In IE however, I run into an issue. For some reason when I upload a file the save file dialogue pops up and asks me to download the file I just uploaded. It looks like it's asking  me to download it from the web-servers tmp location however, as that seems to be the file-name and such. However, if I hit cancel and refresh the page I can see that the file I uploaded did actually get uploaded to the server.

Here is how the upload process works.

1. Click the upload button. The upload button is the standard file input form element hidden and placed over a styled version of the button. Clicking on this causes the "Choose a file" dialogue to open.
2. Select a file and click "Open". A modal dialogue pops up asking you for some further information about the file. The modal is part of the same form element but remains invisible until you click Upload button
3. Clicking save in the modal causes the file to be uploaded. The "action" attribute on the form is pointed to a page and the target is the iframe.
4. **The iFrame is polled a few times every second to see if it's contents have changed. When the file is uploaded a "success" message appears in the iframe. Since it belongs to the same domain, I scrape the content within the iframe.**
5. Once the iFrame says that the file has been uploaded, I use some JS to update the application with the name of the file

Since I can't use Firebug in IE, I have to stick to utilizing Microsofts Web Developer Toolbar, which makes it very hard to figure out if the bolded step is actually occuring. It seems like it should, since the file IS being uploaded. It is just getting interrupted by that file download dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one seems to have an answer, I'll post the fix I found. I doubt it's perfect, but it's the best solution I could come up with.

---

It turned out to be an issue with the polling as suspected. The fix ended up being instead of outputting json to the iFrame, just output some JavaScript that calls a function that updates the main window. That simple.

Comment: I am very surprised this isnt't a common problem with a good answer :(